# How to create key/value array by normal array?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkc1vaor/):

```
var config = function(){
    return {
        name: ["john", "lucy", "lily"],
        age: ["22", "21", "22"],
        gender: ["male", "female", "female"],
        people: function(index){
            index--;
            this.name = name[index];
            this.age = age[index];
            this.gender = gender[index];
        },
        people2: function(index){
            index--;
            this["name"] = name[index];
            this["age"] = age[index];
            this["gender"] = gender[index];
        },
    };
}();

alert(config.people(1).name);
alert(config.people2(1).name);
```

I can get the value by code like:

```
config.name[1];
```

I want to restructure a key/value array like:

```
{name:"john",age:22,gender:male}
```

The index value delegates the first, second and third people info. 
Can anyone help me to get the code working? I'm stuck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return an object as a result

```js
var config = function() {
  return {
    name: ["john", "lucy", "lily"],
    age: ["22", "21", "22"],
    gender: ["male", "female", "female"],
    people: function(index) {
      index--;
      return {
        name: this.name[index],
        age: this.age[index],
        gender: this.gender[index]
      };
    }
  };
}();

alert(config.people(1).name);
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is, without changing much of your code, as follows:

```
var config = function(){
    var name = ["john", "lucy", "lily"],
        age = ["22", "21", "22"],
        gender = ["male", "female", "female"];
    return {
        people: function(index){
           return {
             name: name[index],
             age: age[index],
             gender: gender[index]
           }   
        }
    };
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to restructure the config object (smashing the arrays)

```
    var config = function(){
    return {
        name: ["john", "lucy", "lily"],
        age: ["22", "21", "22"],
        gender: ["male", "female", "female"],
        people: function(index){
            index--;
            this.name = this.name[index];
            this.age = this.age[index];
            this.gender = this.gender[index];
        },
    };
}();

config
***Object {name: Array[3], age: Array[3], gender: Array[3], people: function}
config.people(1)
config
***Object {name: "john", age: "22", gender: "male", people: function}
```